# How to handle files that should exist after a dpkg downgrade but are deleted instead

Tags: package-management, dpkg

We have a product based on a Raspberry Pi/Raspbian and use Debian packages to roll out upgrades to the software (written in Python).

I'm having an issue with getting a new package installing correct, specifically with providing a working downgrade path. I'm a regular user of Debian, but new to the world of package management.

Our package has a few files and scripts in `/usr/local/bin`. However, these files are *not* part of the `DEBIAN` folder of the package. They are copied onto the SD card during production of our product.

The package I am creating now needs to replace one of these files, so I created a `DEBIAN/usr/local/bin` folder in the package with the new file in.

This works fine for upgrading with my new package, but when *downgrading*, `dpkg` deletes the new file and tries to delete the `/usr/local/bin` folder, because as far as it is concerned it they didn't previously exist. The file is required by the old version of the package and so it fails to correctly install and run.

I have tried using the `pre\post inst\rm` scripts in the new package to make a copy of the file on install and copy it back afterwards on removal, but my understanding is that the ordering of the operations means this will not succeed, as the deletion occurs after the new package has run all of its scripts.

Is there a way to prevent deletion of this file during a downgrade?

I hope I have made the problem clear.

Comment: While possible, `dpkg/apt` was never designed with downgrade support in mind. Also, dpkg packages should never touch `/usr/local`. The reason it tries to remove it because dpkg thinks your package owns all of `/usr/local/bin` (which it does).

Comment: Yeah we are certainly abusing it to some extent. Its an embedded system that we're in full control of and that combined with the fact that the original developers were not experts in this domain has led us here.

Comment: Have your package put the files somewhere else (`/opt/foo/bin` or wherever) and make links or copy them to `/usr/local/bin/` in `postinst`. Then the package won't own the `/usr/local/bin` directory. Also, are you sure it works "fine for upgrading"? Generally `dpkg` will not overwrite a file that *was* not owned by any package, with a file that is now owned by one.

Comment: @muru Thanks, this was a good solution. I'm pretty sure my original attempt worked for upgrading, but since I've moved it to a directory in `/opt/` it doesn't matter now anyway. Thanks for the assistance, I'd accept as an answer if it wasn't a comment.

Comment: @jfowkes you can post exactly what you did as an answer!

Comment: @jordanm `dpkg` was very much designed with downgrades in mind, see for example its maintainer script flow charts to see to what extent. :) Of course supporting downgrades in the packages might be too hard to maintain and test so this is a distribution policy whether to support this at all.

Comment: @muru `dpkg` only takes into account pathnames tracked by itself in its database, if there is a pathname not previously owned by dpkg being shipped by a new package, then that pathname will be silently taken over. This is in line with how configuration files vs conffiles are handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was pretty much that suggested by @muru in comments:

- Put the new files in `/opt/appname/bin` in the package
- In `postinst`, backup files in `/usr/local/bin` and replace with symlinks to `/opt/appname/bin`.
- In `postrm`, remove the symlinks and restore the backups, if they exist.

Comment: While using /opt certainly works, you could as well use /usr/bin, that way if some package from the distribution you are basing on provides it too, you'll get an explicit file conflict instead of a silent override at run-time depending on which of the bin directories takes precedence in `PATH`.